# Editing Column in Joined SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, left-join, guid

I am working on a wordpress site where I need to change the upload path for all attachment images (I have no clue why the client initially selected to not have them organized.)

This is what I am running to select my attachments, and grab what the parent posts' post date was so I can correctly grab only what I want.

```
select a.id as child_post_id, a.guid as upload_path, b.post_date as parent_post_date
from wp_posts a
left outer join wp_posts b
on a.post_parent = b.id
where 
a.post_type = 'attachment'
and b.post_date between '2015-11-17 00:00:00' and '2015-11-17 23:59:59'
```

Which pulls up the 8 or so image attachments I am looking for in that span as a test and they are paired with the parent posts post id, so I know I am getting what I want.

Now I want to replace a portion of the value in the guid column, so I am doing a replace in the outputted column of "upload_path"

```
update upload_path
set upload_path = replace(upload_path, 'wp-content/uploads/', 'wp-content/uploads/2015/11/')
;
```

This will cause a failure of syntax and I feel like I'm pulling an odd manuever so searching for an answer has been difficult.

I'm not super experienced going deeper in SQL, but I'm trying to learn.

Do I need to save this query and then run an update on that saved query?

This is probably an easy fix, can someone please help me out- just point me in the right direction, please.

Running mysql 5.1.73 (we have to run what the production server is running)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it turns out, I was trying to run an update within a select statement. Which is a no-go.

I had to run an update statement and then define the inner join and declare each "where" as a limiter within that command. using the "and" syntax.

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS a
INNER JOIN wp_posts AS b ON a.post_parent = b.id
and a.post_type = 'attachment'
and b.post_date between '2015-11-17 00:00:00' and '2015-11-17 23:59:59'
set a.guid = replace(a.guid, 'wp-content/uploads/', 'wp-content/uploads/2015/11/')
limit 0,30
;
```

Wonderful learning experience. Thanks to all that took a look.

Comment: BTW the one downvote is from someone who got mad I didn't choose his incorrect solution